# Lista em Python com valores não repetidos sem usar função set?

Tags: python, lista, loop

Como posso criar uma lista a partir da soma de duas anteriores sem que algum valor apareça repetido, sem usar a função `set`?

Exemplo:

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3]
>>>b = [3, 4, 5]
>>>c = a + b
>>>print c
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Obs.: Não posso usar a função set para criar um conjunto pois ainda não vi esse termo nas aulas de ICC. Estou nos exercícios de laços (`while`), mas no modo que escrevi o programa (errado, quase certo) não utilizei laços.

Se puderem me ajudar utilizando laços, seria interessante

Como estou fazendo sem o while:

```
a = int(raw_input())
x = range(0, a, 3)
y = range(0, a, 5)
lista = x + y
soma = sum(lista) 
print soma
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer seria assim:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]

c = []

for elemento in a:
    c.append(elemento)

for elemento in b:
    if elemento not in c:
        c.append(elemento)
```

O que estamos fazendo é: para cada elemento da primeira lista, colocamos na lista de resultado. Depois, para cada elemento da segunda lista, se ele já não está na lista resultado, colocamos.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Mas o termo append ainda não faz parte do meu vocabulário Python também :x

Comment: É como você coloca novos elementos no fim da lista. Você pode trocar por `c = c + [elemento]` , mas assim você está gerando várias listas desnecessariamente.

Comment: Entendo.. Mas creio que assim seja mais adequado à minha situação. Poderia me mostrar como seria utilizando a função While? O programa deve receber um valor n e imprimir a soma de todos os valores menores que n e que sejam múltiplos de 3 e 5. O problema que tive é que 3 e 5 possuem múltiplos em comum, como 15 por exemplo, e ele não deve ser utilizado duas vezes na soma.

Comment: Você não estudou for ainda? for é a estrutura de repetição mais adequada para percorrer listas.

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza: fica a dica: você só precisa da soma. Não precisa calcular a lista dos números...

Comment: Editei a pergunta ^^

Comment: Sim, estudei for, não diretamente, mas já utilizei muitas vezes.

Comment: De qualquer forma, me parece que você está indo por um caminho um caminho mais difícil do que deveria. Por que não abre uma pergunta na tag algoritmos (independente de linguagem) descrevendo em detalhes o seu problema e o que tentou até agora para resolvê-lo?

Comment: Entendo.. Mas busco o caminho que utiliza os termos que já conheço. Seguirei seu conselho, obrigado!

Comment: Fiz uma nova pergunta com a tag que indicou, e ela foi negativada...

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada

Comment: @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza Tomei a liberdade de editar sua pergunta para deixar no formato mais adequado a questões de algoritmos. Em breve a edição vai entrar no ar, daí você olha e vê se concorda que está melhor daquele jeito.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da forma mais direta:

- Usando laços, você pode testar se um dado elemento da segunda está na primeira lista (e por ele no final se não estiver)
- Com um outro laço, você pode repetir esse processo para inserir cada elemento da segunda lista na primeira

O ruim da forma direta é que o tempo de execução fica bem lento se suas listas forem grandes. Mais precisamente, se suas listas tiverem N elementos, o tempo para fazer um "merge" da forma direta será da ordem de N<sup>2</sup>

Podemos diminuir esse tempo para algo da ordem de N*LOG(N) se aproveitarmos o fato dos elementos da lista serem ordenáveis (isso é o set faz por trás dos panos, mais ou menos). Se você ordenar as duas listas, dá pra fazer o merge delas em uma única passada. É claro, pra fazer isso você vai ter que aprender a ordenar um vetor de forma eficiente, o que é um assunto para outra aula :P

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esta questão podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]

c = list()
for item in chain(a, b):
    if item not in c:
        c.append(item)

c.sort()
print(f'\033[32mA lista resultante é: {c}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código, o laço de repetição `for` percorre simultaneamente as duas listas `a` e `b`, com ajuda do método `chain` da biblioteca `itertools`, verificando se cada item da cada uma das listas está contido na lista `c`. Caso **negativo**, o respectivo valor da respectiva lista é adicionado na lista `c`. Caso **positivo**, o referido valor não é adicionado na lista `c`.

Terminado de ter adicionado todos os valores sem repetições, a lista `c` é ordenada em forma crescente e, posteriormente, a mesma é exibida.

Agora, imagine se desejássemos realizar estas operações em duas listas quaisquer. Como poderíamos resolver? Neste caso devemos implementar um código que possa manipular duas listas quaisquer. Para isso podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from itertools import chain

a = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores da 1ª lista: ').split()))
b = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores da 2ª lista: ').split()))

c = list()
for item in chain(a, b):
    if item not in c:
        c.append(item)

c.sort()
print(f'\033[32mA lista resultante é: {c}')
```

Quando executamos este segundo código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores da 1ª lista:`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da 1ª lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, recebemos a segunda mensagem: `Digite os valores da 2ª lista:`. Neste momento devemos inserir todos os valores da segunda lista do mesmo jeito que inserimos na primeira.

Depois de ter inserido todos os valores nas duas listas o laço de repetição for realizará as mesmas operações descritas no primeiro código.

**Qual é a diferença entre o primeiro e segundo código?**

O **primeiro** código só é capaz de trabalhar com exclusivamente as duas listas inseridas previamente no código. Já o segundo código é capaz de trabalhar com **quaisquer** duas listas e com quaisquer **quantidades** de valores - em cada uma delas.